# Wpf groupstyle wrap panel

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I use a group style with ItemsPanelTemplate,
But I want the gorup to be stack horizntal and the wrappanel like this:

```
*************
*a:1 2 3 b:1*
*2 3 c:1 2 3*
*d:1 2 3 e:1*
*2 3 *
*************
```

I tried this:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

and with / without

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>           
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

but it gave me

```
**************
*a:1 2 3 *
*b:1 2 3 *
*c:1 2 3 *
*d:1 2 3 *
*e:1 2 3 *
**************
```

I even tried the opposite way the group style panel to be stack and the list view to be wrap panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use width:

```
 <WrapPanel Width=200px />
```

(the 200px value is for example)